# Включить отображение пароля в теге password по щелчку на checkbox

Tags: html, css

Есть такой код

```
<input type = "password" name = "password" value = "" placeholder="Пароль" class = "password">
            <div class = "hideshowpass">         
                <input type="checkbox" name="glass" id="eye" class="eyes">
                <label for="eye" class="eyes">
                        <img src="img/body-icon-eye-closed.png"
                class="body_icon_eye_closed" name = "img" id="eye1">
                </label>
            </div>
```

к чекбоксу применены такие стили

```
.hideshowpass [type="checkbox"]{
display: none;
}
.hideshowpass label.eyes{
    cursor: pointer;
```

Хотелось бы , чтобы по пометке checkbox показывался пароль во вкладке пароль и менялась картинка на открытый глаз , вместо закрытого

Comment: на чистом css этого не сделать, добавляйте тег js/js-библиотека ...

Answer (score 4):

```js
$('.hideshowpass input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  
  if ($el.is(':checked')) {
   $('.password').attr('type', 'text');
   $('#eye1').attr('src', 'img/body-icon-eye-open.png');
  } else {
   $('.password').attr('type', 'password');
   $('#eye1').attr('src', 'img/body-icon-eye-close.png');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type = "password" name = "password" value = "" placeholder="Пароль" class = "password">
 <div class = "hideshowpass">         
  <input type="checkbox" name="glass" id="eye" class="eyes">
  <label for="eye" class="eyes">
   <img src="img/body-icon-eye-closed.png" class="body_icon_eye_closed" name = "img" id="eye1">
  </label>
 </div>
```